# Как получить jpeg из Android Camera?

Tags: android, java

Как получить jpeg из Android Camera? 
Вроде он возвращается из JpegCallback в параметре  data?
Этот массив можно просто в файл записать?

Answer (score 1):

Пол этой недели задавался этим вопросом. Дела обстоят так: если вы хотите полностью контролировать весь процесс получения изображения, то нужно самому писать код, как, например, по ссылке **shurik**. Но лично у меня такой подход вызвал одни проблемы - периодические вылеты на разных телефонах. На samsung gio, galaxy s - работает, на htc desire, samsung ace, motorola milestone - вылеты. Хрен отладишь.
Я сделал немного проще - через intent и стандартное приложение для камеры:

```
private Uri imageUri;

public void takePhoto(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                 bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                 .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

П.С. код взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent).

Comment: Спасибо, полезно. Два замечания:
-константа TAKE_PICTURE определяется в вашей Activity вами.
-важно, чтобы приложение имело доступ-разрешение не только к камере, но и к write external storage - cтандартный intent не сможет записать в приватную область для файлов вашего приложения.

Comment: совершенно верно, это я не дописал.

Answer (score 0):

[гуглить](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/112272/) пробывали ? :) Достаточно популярный вопрос